# Windows 9x/Me version in variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, windows-98, windows-95

How would you store the Windows 9x/Me version into a variable?

Comment: I want the Windows Version number like Windows 7 has version 6.1.7601 (I want windows 9X version in a variable. Windows 7 was just an example). I wantit to check the version so i can use the easier code for 98/Me to shutdown the computer and the Windows 95 code to shutdown the computer when you are using windows 95.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if `COMMAND.COM` of Windows 95, Windows 98 and Windows Millennium supports assigning the output of a command to an environment variable at all. What is definitely supported as tested by me on a machine running Windows 98 SE is:

```
@echo off
set WinVer=unknown

rem Windows 95
ver | find "4.00.950" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set WinVer=4.00.950

rem Windows 95 SR2
ver | find "4.00.1111" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set WinVer=4.00.1111

rem Windows 98
ver | find "4.10.1998" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set WinVer=4.10.1998

rem Windows 98 SE
ver | find "4.10.2222" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set WinVer=4.10.2222

rem Windows Millennium
ver | find "4.90.3000" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set WinVer=4.90.3000

echo Windows version is: %WinVer%
```

Perhaps better for the task is a batch file like:

```
@echo off
ver | find "4.00." >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto Win95
ver | find "4.10." >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto Win98
ver | find "4.90." >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto WinMe

echo ERROR: Could not determine Windows version!
goto EndBatch

:Win95
echo INFO: Detected OS as Windows 95.
rem More commands to run for Windows 95.
goto EndBatch

:Win98
echo INFO: Detected OS as Windows 98.
rem More commands to run for Windows 98.
goto EndBatch

:WinMe
echo INFO: Detected OS as Windows ME.
rem More commands to run for Windows ME.
goto EndBatch

rem Commands for other versions of Windows.

:EndBatch
```

Please take care not using labels with more than eight characters. It is possible to use longer label names, but for `COMMAND.COM` are only the first eight characters significant, i.e. `goto Windows98` would be interpreted as `goto Windows9` and therefore the batch file execution would continue on the line below a label starting with `Windows9`.

The Windows version strings used here are taken from Wikipedia article [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS).